# flex wrap html and css

Tags: html, css, flexbox

i try to put a articles box content like a blog in my website so... i try to make it up a good website responsive, but the wrap css is not working, everthing is on a column or everythin is on a row, but i want to wrap the boxes like, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, when the screen size change bigger or smoller...
i am already bad for this, i have some hours tryin to figure it out but i dont get it.
thank you so much.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    background-color: lightslategrey;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
}

a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

Nav {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
}

.container {
    width: 90%;
    margin: auto;
}

/* Navigation */
.nav-main {
    font-size: 17px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    height: 60px;
    padding: 20px 0;
}

.logo-nav {
    font-size: 20px;
}

/* Nav left */
.nav-main ul {
    display: flex;
}

.nav-main ul li {
    padding: 10px;
}

.nav-main ul li a {
    padding: 4px;
}

.nav-main ul li a:hover {
border-bottom: 2px solid #ffffff;
}

.nav-main ul.nav-menu {
flex: 1px;
margin-left: 95px;
}

/*SHOWCASE*/
hr {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.showcase {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    background: url(./img/fondoshowcase.jpeg) no-repeat center center/cover;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

.text-showcase {
    align-items: center;
    width: 90%;
}

.showcase h2,
.showcase p {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.btnshowcase {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 0px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background: darkorange;
}

.btnshowcase:hover {
    opacity: .9;
}

/* News Cards*/
.midcontainer {
    background-color: white;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 650px) {
    .news-container,
    .news-cards {
        display: grid;
    }
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    .news-container {
        display: flex;
        -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
  }

.news-sep{
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.news-container {
    text-align: center;
}

.news-cards {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.news-cards img {
    width: 85%;
    height: 30%;
    min-height: 180px;
    max-width: 85%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Marcos Canela</title>
    <!--font awesome-->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/335ba1c44e.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!--CUSTOM CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="head">
           <nav class="nav-main">
               <a href=""><h1 class="logo-nav"> Marcos Canela </h1></a>
               <ul class="nav-menu">
                   <li>
                    <a href="#">Inicio</a>
                   </li>
                   <li>
                    <a href="#">Inicio</a>
                   </li>
                   <li>
                    <a href="#">Inicio</a>
                   </li>
                   <li>
                    <a href="#">Inicio</a>
                   </li>
                   <li>
                    <a href="#">Inicio</a>
                   </li>
               </ul>
               <ul class="nav-menu-right">
                  <li>
                     <a href="#">
                         <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                     </a>
                   </li>
               </ul>
           </nav>
           <hr></hr>
             <!-- showcase-->
             <header class="showcase">
                 <div class="text-showcase">
                 <h2>Big new today</h2>
                 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores, sed, nihil ipsum quibusdam eum inventore veniam odit itaque fugit quod quidem placeat delectus quis doloremque ullam facere magni id quia?</p>
                 <a href="#" class="btnshowcase">Click Aqui <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                </div>
                </header>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--News Cards-->
    <div class="midcontainer">
        <hr class="news-sep"></hr>
        <div class="news-container">
            <div class="news-cards">
                <div class="news1">
                    <img src="/Pruebas/Sitio 2/src/img/news1.jpeg" alt="">
                    <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum, expedita! Non nesciunt ab ut, voluptatem inventore distinctio, voluptas, odio officia doloribus libero deserunt. Quisquam accusamus, fugit velit dicta aliquid eum?</p>
                    <a href="#">ver mas <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                </div>
                <div class="news2">
                    <img src="/Pruebas/Sitio 2/src/img/news2.jpeg" alt="">
                    <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum, expedita! Non nesciunt ab ut, voluptatem inventore distinctio, voluptas, odio officia doloribus libero deserunt. Quisquam accusamus, fugit velit dicta aliquid eum?</p>
                    <a href="#">ver mas <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                </div>
                <div class="news3">
                    <img src="/Pruebas/Sitio 2/src/img/news3.jpeg" alt="">
                    <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum, expedita! Non nesciunt ab ut, voluptatem inventore distinctio, voluptas, odio officia doloribus libero deserunt. Quisquam accusamus, fugit velit dicta aliquid eum?</p>
                    <a href="#">ver mas <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                </div>
                <div class="news4">
                    <img src="/Pruebas/Sitio 2/src/img/news4.jpeg" alt="">
                    <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum, expedita! Non nesciunt ab ut, voluptatem inventore distinctio, voluptas, odio officia doloribus libero deserunt. Quisquam accusamus, fugit velit dicta aliquid eum?</p>
                    <a href="#">ver mas <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you want to wrap the content inside <nav> to show below each other when screen size is small?

Comment: is this what you try to do ? https://jsfiddle.net/9opwaubt/  -/- Aside :  if you did not know already : https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ and  https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/ can help to sort out your layout issues.

Comment: dude, its very difficult to understand, what you want to achieve! you should have added minimal code, and explained with help of some image, what atleast you want to get?

Comment: Sorry bro, i add a example of what am looking for: https://www.hostinger.mx/ in the index there is a section bellow the brand slide that has a table content with prices that wraps the conten when we change the size of the window.... like this: https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_flexbox_flex-wrap_wrap but in my code html in the last part, i have a seccion call it NEWS-CARDS but this is not wrapping, when i change the size of the window the desing is not moving the like the example, it looks so hermetic and inflexible.